# Rotate text within a shape on draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I have some triangles which contain text, but I want the text to always be aligned in the same orientation to the page, even when the shape itself is rotated, which means, I guess, that I need to be able to rotate the text independently of the shape. I think it can be done in the XML but does anyone know of a way it can be done in the GUI?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this was possible at the time you posted your question, but this is possible, at least at 90° intervals now. See screenshot below.

[image: Shape-only Rotation]